# How can I initialize a custom SwiftUI View from a static var that conforms to a protocol

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, dependency-injection

I am attempting to implement Dependency Injection with a SwiftUI `View` by assigning the Type of a View to a static var that conforms to a `CustomViewInterface` protocol.

`static var MyCustomView: any CustomViewInterface.Type = CustomView.self`

The goal being to inject any `View` that conforms to that protocol and initialize it inside the receiving class.

When I initialize the custom SwiftUI `View` inside the `body` block of the `ContentView` I get the error

`Type 'any CustomViewInterface' cannot conform to 'View'`.

Although when I print out the `type(of:` of the View Type it is `CustomView` (not `CustomViewInterface`) I don't understand why the `Type` is different when it's initialized inside the `body` block of the `ContentView` vs in the initializer of the `DefaultComponentImplementation` class.

My question is, how can I initialize a custom SwiftUI View from a static var that conforms to a protocol. The end goal is to use Dependency Injection for SwiftUI Views.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let defaultComponenetImplementaion = DefaultComponentImplementation()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CustomView(title: "cat") // this works
            DefaultComponentImplementation.MyCustomView.init(title: "mouse") // error: Type 'any CustomViewInterface' cannot conform to 'View'
        }
    }
}

protocol CustomViewInterface: View {
    var title: String { get set }

    init(title: String)
}

struct CustomView: CustomViewInterface {
    var title: String

    var body: some View {
        Text(title)
    }
}

class DefaultComponentImplementation {
    static var MyCustomView: any CustomViewInterface.Type = CustomView.self
    
    init() {
        print(type(of: DefaultComponentImplementation.MyCustomView.init(title: "cat"))) // prints CustomView
    }
}
```

Comment: Protocols are a recipe, you need the actual cake to do something.

Comment: Why not use the built in dependency injection `EnvironmentKey` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot use `any View`, or in this case `any CustomViewInterface`, in a view builder. `any CustomViewInterface` does not conform to `View`. The reason for this is [a rather long story](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33112559/5133585). It basically boils down to the fact that `View` has certain static requirements that an existential type does not possess, like the `Body` associated type. `(any CustomViewInterface).Body` is not a thing.

Since you want to show different kinds of views depending on a metatype property, erasing them to `AnyView` (which unlike `any View`, *is* a concrete type) should work.

Add an extension to erase `any CustomViewInterface` to `AnyView`:

```
extension CustomViewInterface{
    func toAnyView() -> AnyView {
        AnyView(self)
    }
}
```

Then

```
DefaultComponentImplementation.MyCustomView.init(title: "mouse").toAnyView()
```

Comment: That's great, it does work! However, I am still confused about when the compiler knows what the concrete type is. I would expect that after the initialization `DefaultComponentImplementation.MyCustomView.init(title: "mouse")` the concrete type is known? Then that type is erase with `.toAnyView()` Can you explain why the `body` block interprets that line as a protocol until `toAnyView()` is called?

Comment: @NatePotter You declared `MyCustomView` to be of type `any CustomViewInterface.Type`, so calling `init` on that creates a `any CustomViewInterface`. The compiler only knows the *declared* type and only uses the declared type to analyse your code.